# Scala 2 artifact in Scala 3 project: conflicting cross-version suffixes

Tags: scala, scala-3

I want to use Scala 2 library that wasn't migrated to Scala 3 yet in my Scala 3 project. When I add it as a dependency I get error  `Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: There's the `for3Use2.13` option in SBT (not sure of the name) or the opposite one.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the 2.13 scala-collection-compat like this:

```
    excludeDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-collection-compat_2.13"
```

Comment: This seems more of a recommendation, than a solution. Did it fix your problem ?

Comment: Yes. It fixed the problem